# MongoDB 4 Shards in a Sharding Cluster but there is only using 3 and it's not well distribuited

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing, sharding

I have a shard cluster with 4 different shards. I'm testing different configurations and shard keys.

I have a collection with 5,000,000 of documents and I'm sharding the collection.
But there are only 3 shards in use, and there are 2 with a lot of chunks and the other one has only 1 chunk.

```
sh.status()
```

is like that:

```
sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("55807b06780a890b28354352")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "sh1_rs1",  "host" : "sh1_rs1/192.168.0.126:27018,192.168.0.189:27017,192.168.0.190:27018" }
    {  "_id" : "sh2_rs1",  "host" : "sh2_rs1/192.168.0.222:27018,192.168.0.229:27018,192.168.0.59:27018" }
    {  "_id" : "sh3_rs1",  "host" : "sh3_rs1/192.168.0.188:27018" }
    {  "_id" : "sh4_rs1",  "host" : "sh4_rs1/192.168.0.228:27018" }
  balancer:
    Currently enabled:  yes
    Currently running:  no
    Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
    Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
        8360 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: migrate already in progress', from sh1_rs1 to sh4_rs1
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "sh1_rs1" }
    {  "_id" : "infonavit",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "sh1_rs1" }
    {  "_id" : "test_shard",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "sh1_rs1" }
        test_shard.coll
            shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
            chunks:
                sh1_rs1 1
                sh2_rs1 1
                sh3_rs1 1
            { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("557f394e256393d0ee325b14") } on : sh2_rs1 Timestamp(2, 0) 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("557f394e256393d0ee325b14") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("5581969fe3a93c05ea233e56") } on : sh3_rs1 Timestamp(3, 0) 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("5581969fe3a93c05ea233e56") } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : sh1_rs1 Timestamp(3, 1) 
    {  "_id" : "infonavit_cartera",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "sh1_rs1" }
        infonavit_cartera.creditos
            shard key: { "saldo_actual" : 1 }
            chunks:
                sh1_rs1 43
                sh2_rs1 1
                sh3_rs1 37
            too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Shouldn't there be one config server ?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 config servers, but the shard still not balancing de info

Comment: So how many servers do you have in total? 5?

Comment: I have 8 machines. Each one is running a mongod process. But there are only 4 shards. Each shard has a replica member as a secondary and a primary.

Comment: What is the type and cardinality of `saldo_actual`? A [good shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/) needs to have high cardinality and a good degree of randomness in order to distribute writes to multiple shards. If the chunks aren't being naturally distributed by your shard key choice, they will have to be moved by the balancer. You mention only having 2 config servers .. for production use you should always have 3 (in fact, `mongos` should refuse to start up unless you have 1 or 3 config servers). Can you confirm the version of MongoDB being used?

Comment: Sorry, i though i had 2 config servers, but you are right, there is only 1 server. Do you think that's the caouse?

Comment: Looks like there is some connection problem. Resolve connection issue - 8360 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: migrate already in progress', from sh1_rs1 to sh4_rs1

Comment: I think that this is because my computer memory is over. When i arrived to my work computer today i saw that i have no memory. Could that be the reason?